# Predicate logic for finite/infinite universe

Tags: logic, proof-theory

For our course in Mathematical Methods for Computer Science, we need some help conserning finite/infinite universes for predicate logic.
We consider the following formulas:
$$
R = \forall x \forall y(P(x ,y) \land P(y, x) \to x= y )
$$
$$
S = \forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \lor P(y, x))
$$
$$
T = \forall x \forall y (P(x,y) \land P(y,z) \to P(x,z))
$$
$$
R \land S \land T \to \exists x \forall y P(x,y)
$$
Now we are supposed to figure for which interpretations this formula is true/false.
In the first step we found an counterexample for an infinite universe.
Because of this we know that this formula doesn't work for all infinite universes.
The problem is now to show that it works for all finite universes. So far our only approach is the fact that for a finite universe there is a finite number of combinations for *x* and *y*. But we don't know how to use them for our approach. We will be grateful for a hint on how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget about the number of combinations. Think about what those axioms actually *mean*.

Comment: I assume the $\exists x \forall x P(x,y)$ is supposed to be $\exists x \forall y P(x,y)$?

Comment: You have mentioned a bunch of formulas. Which one is "this formula"? My wild guess: "this formula" is $R\land S\land T.$

Answer (score 2):

HINT

The statements $R$, $S$, and $T$ state that the binary relation $P$ is anti-symmetric, total, and transitive, respectively. This means that you are dealing with a total order; roughly, all objects can be thought of as being 'lined up' from 'left' to right', where there is a $P$ relation between objects $x$ and $y$ if and only if $x$ is to the left of $y$ or $x=y$.  Now, in an infinite line-up, there is no one object at either end, but in a finite line-up, there is.